# AppRegistryNotReady error when trying to install django-seo

Tags: python, django

I ran `pip install djangoseo` and then confirmed it with pip freeze

Added `rollyourown.seo` to my `INSTALLED_APPS` setting

Added `"django.core.context_processors.request"` to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting

When I try to run python `manage.py syncdb` or run my application I get the following error

```
AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Comment: You are following very old instructions - `syncdb` was replaced by `migrate` in Django 1.7, and the `TEMPLATES` dict replaced individual `TEMPLATE_*` settings in Django 1.8. It looks like [`django-seo`](https://github.com/willhardy/django-seo) has not been updated in several years, so it's not going to work with modern versions of Django.

Comment: i am getting same error with python manage.py migrate , django version:-1.11.7

Comment: As I said, django-seo is not going to work with modern versions of Django. I would avoid using it because it is not maintained.

Comment: ok . thanks . can u suggest me any other solution or link for seo

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have any other suggestions, and asking for recommendations is off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.") is raised when you try to access models before the django even loads it. In apps.py file, override the ready method which is a trigger stating django has done its part, and import of models, or any model related stuff should go in there.

```
functions.py

def whatever():
    from . import models


__init__.py

from .functions import whatever
```

"whatever" function might internally be importing models. So at the start of the app, you try importing whatever which imports models, while django hasn't still finished loading it yet and hence the exception.

Solution:

```
__init__.py

default_app_config = 'users.apps.UserConfig'


apps.py

class UserConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'users'

    def ready(self):
        try:
            from .functions import whatever

        except Exception as e:
            print("DON'T WORRY")
```

Comment: still facing same issue

Comment: Was it working before you changed it to somthing else?